# Shopify - Display all products with the same vendor as current product

Tags: shopify, product, liquid, vendor

We built our Shopify site so that the only product variants would be size. However, we also wanted to display different styles of the same product as thumbnail links on product pages. This was done using the vendor attribute and the following liquid code:

```
             {% assign vendor = product.vendor %}
             {% assign handle = product.handle %}
             {% assign counter = '' %}
             {% for product in collections['shop-all'].products %}
             {% if vendor == product.vendor and counter.size < 4 and handle != product.handle %}
             {% capture temp %}{{ counter }}*{% endcapture %}
             {% assign counter = temp %}
             <div class="recommendations_img">
             <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" title="{{ product.title }}">
             <img src="{{ product.images.first | product_img_url: 'small' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}" />
             </a>       
             </div><!-- .recommendations_img -->
             {% endif %}    
             {% endfor %}
```

However, this doesn't work because of Shopify's 50 product limit per page. The pagination workaround doesn't work either because it's on a product page.

**So this is what we need:**

To display all products (image and link only) that match the same vendor as the current product. Something more along these lines:

```
{% assign vendor_handle = vendor | handleize %}
{% for product in all_products[vendor_handle].vendor %}
  <a href="{{ product.url }}" title="{{ product.title }}">
         <img src="{{ product.images.first | product_img_url: 'small' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.